# Client Server TCP in Python 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: python, python-3.x

Im trying to create a client server, where server stores list of strings and client keeps asking if user wants another one till they indicate no. Im trying to figure out how to send the whole list over and how to iterate it properly. In my client I get the error 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode' which is the "clientSocket.send(msg.encode())" part.

**Server**

```
from random import choice
import socket
Port =13000
Server= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
Server.bind((socket.gethostname(),Port))
Server.listen(1)
print ("The server is ready to recieve ")

quotes = ["Not my circus, not my monkeys",
         "Don't eat yellow snow",
         "Where's Waldo?"]

while True:
    connectionSocket, addr = Server.accept()
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(2048)
    for i in range (len(quotes)):
        connectionSocket.sendall(quotes.encode())
    **new edit**
    for i in quotes:
        connectionSocket.sendall(i.encode())

Server.close()
```

**Client**

```
from random import choice
import socket

serverName = socket.gethostname()
Port=13000
clientSocket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
clientSocket.connect((serverName,Port))
msg = "Quote is: "
while True:
    clientSocket.send(msg.encode())
    msg = clientSocket.recv(2048)
    print(msg.decode())

    x = input(("Would you like another quote? Type 'yes' or 'no' "))
    if x =='yes':
       pass
    elif x == 'no':
        print ("Thanks for using me, bye! ")
        quit()
    else:
        print("Invalid input try again")


clientSocket.close()
```

Comment: You can't `encode()` a list, you have to encode each string *in* the list.

Comment: Change `connectionSocket.sendall(quotes.encode())` to `connectionSocket.sendall(quotes[i].encode())`

Comment: instead of `for i in range (len(quotes)):` you can use `for item in quotes:` and then you can send `connectionSocket.sendall(item.encode())`

Comment: Thanks that solved the iteration problem.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the first iteration, your `msg` variable is already encoded, because `recv` returns type `bytes`. The best solution is to declare `msg = b"Quote is: "` before the `while` loop, and then change `msg.encode()` to simply `msg`